# add spelling error word in project level dictionary

Tags: android

In my project, I have too many word show spelling error. I want to add all spelling error word in the project level dictionary. In my project, it shows 3021 error. My question is `how I add all error word in project level dictionary using shortcut way?`

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the step:**

1. `Inspect code` whole project.
2. Select add project level or application level which you want. Just click then all spelling error word is going to save.